# The url problem I have in accessing the "assets" folder in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, url, assets, laravel-10

since I do not want to take up your time, I will first summarize the problem very briefly. And I can say that I have read and tried almost all the other messages that have opened regarding the similar problem. But my problem is never solved.

**Summary**:
I am running Laravel 10 on a virtual server I created on Xampp on my computer. When I enter the "cmd.dev" address, everything seems fine, but no css and js are loaded in addresses such as cms.dev/account/detail.

**Extended**:
I made a clean installation of Laravel 10 in the "C:\xampp\htdocs\cms" directory. As in my previous Laravel projects, I added the necessary information to the "httpd-vhosts.conf" file located in the "C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra" directory to create a virtual server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@cms.dev
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/cms/public/"
ServerName cms.dev
ServerAlias www.cms.dev
ErrorLog "logs/cms.dev-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/cms.dev-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And of course I added the necessary line to the "hosts" file.

```
127.0.0.1 cms.dev
```

When I enter "cms.dev" from the browser, there is no problem. All my css or js files in Laravel "public/assets" are loaded without any problems and the interface I want appears. Even when I go to the cms.dev/account page, for example, there is no problem. However, when there is another slash in the url, for example, when I enter the cms.dev/account/detail page, unfortunately, files such as css etc. are not loaded. When I check the source code everything is correct
("cms.dev/assets/vendor/css/core.css" ) appears. When I say examine the page, the path it shows is ("cms.dev/account/assets/vendor/css/core.css"). So it seems that the account parameter has been inserted.

I have previously implemented 3 projects on Laravel 9 with this exact installation and settings and have never experienced any similar problems. What is the problem that is causing me to experience this in Laravel 10? I'm really about to go crazy. Thank you very much to everyone in advance.

I tested everything by doing a clean install.

Laravel Version: v10.31.0

PHP Version: v8.2.4

My "assets" folder is located in Laravel's "public" folder and contains css and js folders. The only change I made was to specify the APP_URL variable in the ".env" file:

APP_URL=http://cms.dev

And then I tried calling my files the same way as in my previous projects:

{{asset('assets/vendor/css/core.css')}}

Since this method did not work, I defined the ASSET_URL variable suggested by Laravel:

ASSET_URL=http://cms.dev/assets

And I called my files like this:

{{asset('vendor/css/core.css')}}

Comment: The obvious first question is: are these files accessible from the URL you're using?

Comment: Merhaba, cevabınız için çok teşekkür ederim. Evet, dosyalar orada ve yukarıda belirtilen URL'leri girdiğimde hepsine erişebiliyorum. Aslında örneklerde de belirttiğim gibi ana sayfaya girdiğimde her şey çok güzel çalışıyor. Ancak bahsettiğim diğer yollara gittiğimde **(Örneğin: cms.dev/account/detail)** kaynak kodunda her şey güzel ve doğru görünüyor ancak sayfayı incelemeye çalıştığımda "Kaynak yüklenemedi : sunucu, konsolda 404 (Not) durumuyla yanıt verdi. Bulundu)" hatası ve url, **"cms.dev/account/assets/vendor/css/core.css"** olarak görünüyor :(

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you will need to add a forward slash to the front of the path you are referencing in the asset function, so that the base path for the file becomes the public folder.

```
APP_URL=http://cms.dev
```

and then in your files

```
{{asset('/assets/vendor/css/core.css')}}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help, but I tried this too and unfortunately it did not work.

My first attempt was as follows:
ASSET_URL=http://cms.dev/assets
{{asset('/vendor/css/core.css')}}

My second attempt was as follows (i.e. the method you specified):
(I removed the "ASSET_URL" variable from the .env file, of course)
APP_URL=http://cms.dev
{{asset('/assets/vendor/css/core.css')}}

Unfortunately, the same problem continues. Everything works fine on the home page, but when I go to "cms.dev/account/detail", unfortunately the assets are not loaded. I am about to go crazy.